# Creating bootable usb of windows

Tags: windows-7, usb-flash-drive, bootable-media, fat32, rufus

I've been trying to create a bootable usb of windows 7 setup to do a clean installation on my laptop.I have a 32 GB Sandisk USB (3.0) and my hard drive is GPT. At first, I used Rufus in MBR partition scheme and selected target device as UEFI(CSM) because my UEFI device has support for legeacy bios ( I saw the option in my UEFI settings.) But everytime I tried to boot from the usb, it kept showing no media present. I thought rufus formatting my usb as ntfs was the problem( fat32 oprion was unavailable ). But when I tried making the bootable usb with YUMI with FAT32 selected, it said not enough disk space in the middle of the proccess(where 7zip extracts the files to the usb). I think it's because my iso is too large(over 5 GB). So in this situation, what do i have to do to successfully make working bootable usb of windows 7 ?

Comment: Does it has to be Windows 7? For Windows 10 you could simply use the MediaCreator tool by Microsoft and as you have a Window 7 license you could install Windows 10 and activate it using your Windows 7 license key.

Comment: Ik about media creation tool, but i wrote windows 7 for a reason. I have to install it for a certain purpose

Comment: Then I would simply ask around if one of your friends have a USB CD/DVD drive that you could borrow for the installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> fat32 option was unavailable

> my iso is too large (over 5 GB)

Then it looks like you are not using an official Microsoft Windows 7 retail ISO. If you did, then your ISO would be smaller than 4 GB, and, when creating a drive for UEFI boot, Rufus would also allow you to select FAT32 as the file system.

I'm afraid that, because there is no way to tell how your **unofficial** ISO might have been altered, possibly in ways that completely break USB boot, you're probably not going to get much help here.

I would therefore encourage you to get your hands on an official Microsoft Windows 7 retail ISO, and see if that works better.

Comment: Unfortunately, i cant get an official iso because they are no longer available in the Microsoft website. I have a physical dvd of windows 7 lying around tho. But everytime i boot it from boot options, it doesn't recognize the media and skips into booting my hdd.

Comment: I believe Windows 7 ISOs are still available at https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows7.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much !